# How to use a joomla plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla

I have a plugin that i have installed & I am able to view it on the plugin manager , however i have no idea how to use it on the template i.e is it possible to assign plugins to positions? I am new to joomla assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Be specific. What you want to achieve? What is your requirement. BTQ it depends on the plugin. You even not mentioned whether the plugin is custom.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins respond to (are triggered by) events. They are not meant to be attached to an specific position (like modules are). What you should do is to enable it, then it'll start listening for some event(s). Did you build this plugin yourself? If it's someone else's it's commonplace to use `{myplugin} parameters {/myplugin}` syntaxis, so that you can call it from any editor field. In that case you could have a module with an editor field, place it in any position you want and then call your plugin from it.

For more information about plugins, see http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin